# Error in React: Generic type 'DatePickerProps' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik

DatePicker Component:

```
import React from "react"
import AdapterDateFns from '@mui/lab/AdapterDateFns';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/lab';
import { DatePicker, DatePickerProps } from '@mui/lab';

const FormikDatePicker: React.FunctionComponent<DatePickerProps> = ({
    ...rest
}) => {
    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
            <DatePicker
                {...rest}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    )
}

export default FormikDatePicker
```

FormikDatePicker Component:

```
import React from "react"
import { FormHelperText } from "@mui/material"
import { useFormikContext } from "formik"
import { getFormikInputParams } from "../../../utils/getFormikInputParams"
import DatePicker from "./DatePicker"
import { FormikIdentifier } from "../../../types/formik"
import { DatePickerProps } from "@mui/lab"

type Props = Omit<
    DatePickerProps,
    "onChange" | "value" | "id" | "name"
> &
    FormikIdentifier

const FormikDatePicker: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ ...rest }) => {
    const formik = useFormikContext()
    const id = rest.id || rest.name || ""
    const { error, showError, value } = getFormikInputParams(formik, id)

    return (
        <>
            <DatePicker
                inputFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
                value={value}
                onChange={(date) => formik.setFieldValue(id, date)}
                onClose={() => formik.setFieldTouched(id)}
                {...rest}
            />
            {showError && <FormHelperText error>{error}</FormHelperText>}
        </>
    )
}

export default FormikDatePicker
```

The issue:

[image]

The code was working fine but after updating the material UI to version 5, I am receiving the above error and I have no idea how to resolve it. If you could help that would be great, thank you.

How DatePickerProps is defined:

```
import * as React from 'react';
declare type DatePickerComponent = (<TDate>(props: DatePickerProps<TDate> & React.RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => JSX.Element) & {
    propTypes?: any;
};
/**
 * @ignore - do not document.
 */
declare const DatePicker: DatePickerComponent;
export default DatePicker;
export declare type DatePickerProps<TDate> = Record<any, any>;
```

Comment: You could look at how `DatePickerProps` are defined. From the error message it seems that it's a generic type, so it should be qualified with another type, like `DatePickerProps<Something>`. Looking at its definition should give you some clues what that `Something` type should be.

Comment: @tromgy I added DatePickerProps definition in the description. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: That definition of `DatePickerProps` doesn't make much sense to me, because `TDate` is not actually used in the type. So you should be able to simply do something like `DatePickerProps<null>`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error. `DatePickerProps` is a generic type and requires you to define one. So for example your props could look like this:

```
type Props<T> = Omit<
    DatePickerProps<T>,
    "onChange" | "value" | "id" | "name"
> &
    FormikIdentifier
```

If `DatePickerProps` generic requires some constraints on the generic you need to add those to your Props generic too.

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the source code, I couldn't figure out what types the generics are supposed to be.  I assume dates.  There are actually two generics though:

```
export interface DatePickerProps<TInputDate, TDate> extends ...
```

Maybe not the best answer, but this is working for me without any type errors:

```
type MergedProps = SpotlightIntegrationProps &
  SelectProps &
  DatePickerProps<Date, Date>;
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by giving Dayjs to the argument.

```
interface ICalenderProps extends DatePickerProps<Dayjs>
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced this problem today and fixed it by importing my date picker and localization provider from mui/x-date-pickers. Apparently the date picker from mui/lab is deprecated.
[This is a link about migration from lab to x-pickers](https://mui.com/blog/lab-date-pickers-to-mui-x/) and [this is mui x docs](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/).

Comment: my issue is related to DatePickerProps. even migration doesn't help